# Semantic-ui sticky column bug

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

My sticky implementation does not work correctly.

However, after window resize it works fine!

I use it with Meteor. Semantic-ui version is 2.0.7.

I wonder if my code is correct or if it may be a bug?

Here's my code:

```
  <div class="ui two column doubling stackable grid container">
    <div class="two column row">
      <div id="filter-column" class="three wide column center aligned">
        <div class="ui sticky">


          <div class="ui segment">
            <div class="ui statistic">
              <div class="value">
                {{count plates}}
              </div>
              <div class="label">
                Plates Total
              </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Filter</h2>
            {{#each categories}}
              <button class="fluid ui {{color}} {{isActive _id}} button button-filter">{{name}}</button>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="content-column" class="thirteen wide column">
        <div class="ui link doubling two cards">
          {{#each plates}}
            <div class="card">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="right floated"><i class="euro icon"></i> 17</div>
                <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b8f9370a931b3873db20b61c7fd9513b.jpg"> Manuel K.
              </div>
              <div class="image">
                <img src="{{images.[0].url}}">
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="header">
                  {{title}}
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                  {{#each plateCategories categoryIds}}
                    <i class="ui tiny {{color}} label">{{name}}</i>
                  {{/each}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="extra content">
                <span class="right floated">
                  <i class="history icon"></i>
                  18:00
                </span>
                <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                10/12/2015
              </div>
            </div>
          {{else}}
            No plates yet.
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky({
  context: "#content-column",
  offset: 10
});
```

Comment: Could you please describe the problem in more detail and maybe provide a JSFiddle? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `refresh` method of sticky-ui. This should solve the issue.

```
$('<your sticky element>').sticky('refresh');
```